# Count times ID appears in a table and return in row

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count, row

```
SELECT
Boats.id, Boats.date, Boats.section, Boats.raft, 
river_company.company, river_section.section AS river 
FROM Boats 
INNER JOIN river_company ON Boats.raft = river_company.id 
INNER JOIN river_section ON Boats.section = river_section.id 
ORDER BY Boats.date DESC, river, river_company.company
```

Returns everything I need. But how would I add a [Photos] table and count how many times Boats.id occurs in it and add that to the returned rows.

So if there are 5 photos for boat #17 I want the record for boat #17 to say PhotoCount = 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a `LEFT JOIN` to a sub query as follows:

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(p.id) num, p.boatID FROM photos p GROUP BY p.boatID) 
          sub_photos ON (sub_photos.boatID = Boats.id)
```

And then reference `sub_photos.num` in your `SELECT` fields.

It would look something like this:

```
SELECT     Boats.id, Boats.date, Boats.section, Boats.raft, 
           river_company.company, river_section.section AS river,
           sub_photos.num AS number_of_photos
FROM       Boats 
INNER JOIN river_company ON Boats.raft = river_company.id 
INNER JOIN river_section ON Boats.section = river_section.id 
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT COUNT(p.id) num, p.boatID FROM photos p GROUP BY p.boatID) 
           sub_photos ON (sub_photos.boatID = Boats.id)
ORDER BY   Boats.date DESC, river, river_company.company
```

Comment: Daniel, aside from a minor col name correction, its prefect! Thank you!
Boats.boatID = Boats.ID

Comment: @Tyler: Just noticed, and fixed... I'm glad this helped :)

Answer (score 2):

I presume boatsId is a column in the Photos table? The easiest way would be with a subselect:

```
SELECT ...whatever columns...,

(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Photos WHERE boatsId = Boats.id)

FROM ...rest of your query
```

Comment: Subquery returned more than 1 value.

Comment: If you used this method you would have filter the subselect on boat ID.  I think joining on a subquery is better for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Boats.id,
       Boats.date,
       Boats.section,
       Boats.raft,
       river_company.company,
       river_section.section AS river
       (SELECT count(*) FROM Photos WHERE boatsID = Boats.id)
FROM Boats
INNER JOIN river_company ON Boats.raft = river_company.id 
INNER JOIN river_section ON Boats.section = river_section.id 
ORDER BY Boats.date DESC, river, river_company.company
```

Give this one a try.

Comment: Minor changes and it works great! Thank you.
SELECT Boats.id,
       Boats.date,
       Boats.section,
       Boats.raft,
       river_company.company,
       river_section.section AS river,
       (SELECT count(*) FROM Photos WHERE boatID = Boats.id) as PicCount
FROM Boats
INNER JOIN river_company ON Boats.raft = river_company.id 
INNER JOIN river_section ON Boats.section = river_section.id 
ORDER BY Boats.date DESC, river, river_company.company

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
SELECT 
Boats.id, Boats.date, Boats.section, Boats.raft,  
river_company.company, river_section.section AS river  
Count(Photos.ID) AS PhotoCount
FROM Boats  
INNER JOIN river_company ON Boats.raft = river_company.id  
INNER JOIN river_section ON Boats.section = river_section.id  
OUTER JOIN Photos ON Boats.id = Photos.BoatID ORDER BY Boats.date DESC, river, river_company.company 
GROUP BY
    Boats.id, Boats.date, Boats.section, Boats.raft, river_company.company, river_section.section
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provide any information regarding the structure of the Photos table but something like this should work for you.

```
SELECT
Boats.id, Boats.date, Boats.section, Boats.raft, 
river_company.company, river_section.section AS river,
PhotoCount.NumberOfBoats as PhotoCount 
FROM Boats 
INNER JOIN river_company ON Boats.raft = river_company.id 
INNER JOIN river_section ON Boats.section = river_section.id 
Left Join
(
    Select b2.Id, Count(b2.Id) as NumberOfBoats
    From Boats b2
    Join Photos p on b2.Id = p.BoatId
    Group By b2.Id
)BoatCount on BoatCount.Id = Boats.Id

ORDER BY Boats.date DESC, river, river_company.company
```

Comment: I'll try to post more details in the future. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Another way

```
SELECT DISTINCT
Boats.id, Boats.date, Boats.section, Boats.raft,  
river_company.company, river_section.section AS river,
count(photos.boatid) OVER(PARTITION BY photos.boatid)
FROM Boats  
INNER JOIN river_company ON Boats.raft = river_company.id  
INNER JOIN river_section ON Boats.section = river_section.id
LEFT JOIN photos on photos.boatid = Boats.id
ORDER BY Boats.date DESC, river, river_company.company
```

Answer (score 1):

`Select YourID, COUNT(*) FROM YourTable GROUP BY YourID`

This works just fine for when I'm trying to track down where record count might be different based on an ID or any other column.