# How do I select row based on the number of times it appears in the table?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have my table: call it `tblA`  THis table has three rows, `id`, `sub-id`, and `visibility`

`sub-id` is the primary key (it defines taxonomies for `id`).  I'm trying to build a query that selects every `id` that appears less than three times.

here is an example query/result

`select * from tbla where id = 188002;`

```
+--------+--------+-------------+
| sub-id |  id    | visibility  |
+--------+--------+-------------+
| 284922 | 188002 |      2      |
| 284923 | 188002 |      2      |
| 284924 | 188002 |      0      |
+--------+--------+-------------+
```

From what i've seen [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,180556,180572#msg-180572) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735367/count-times-id-appears-in-a-table-and-return-in-row) it looks like I need to join the table on...itself.  I dont really understand what that accomplishes.

If anyone has insight into this, it is appreciated.  I will continue to research it and update this topic with any additional information I come across.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT id
    FROM tbla
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING COUNT(*) < 3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select all columns from the table, you will have to use @Joe's query in a sub-select:

```
SELECT * FROM tbla a
WHERE a.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT b.id 
               FROM tbla b 
               GROUP BY b.id 
               HAVING COUNT(*) < 3)
```

This query first selects all id's that have fewer than 3 duplicates.
The distinct eliminates duplicates, the query works the same without, but slightly slower.

Next it selects all rows that have an id that meets the criteria in the sub-select i.e. that have fewer than 3 duplicate id's.

The reason that you **cannot** do this in one go is that the `group by` heaps all rows with the same id together into one `super-row` *(for want of a better metafor)* .
You cannot separate out the columns that are not in the group by clause.

The outer select solves this.